# List permissions of environment path with powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl

I would like to write a script which lists/exports the permissions of the directories in Path.

To get the path variables I use `$env:Path` but this lists the variables as one large string. How can I get the variable in a object to proceed further? Next, I would like to get the permissions `get-acl`.

Thanks for your support.

DonQui

Comment: Start by getting it to an array with `$env:path -split ';'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`-split` operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx) to split the string like so,

```
$arr = $env:path -split ";"
$arr
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\windows\system32
C:\windows
...
```

The `$arr` variable contents can be piped to, say, `foreach` for further processing like so,

```
$arr | % {
  $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you arco444

I used the following script to get the list with the permissions:

```
$folders = $env:Path
$folders = $folders.split(";")

foreach ($path in $paths){
    $acl = Get-Acl $path
    $acl.Access
    foreach ($ace in $acl.Access) {
            $obj = New-Object psobject
            $obj | add-member noteproperty -name FolderPath -Value $path
            $obj | add-member noteproperty -name Identity -Value $ace.IdentityReference
            $obj | Add-Member noteproperty -name AccessType -Value $ace.AccessControlType
            $obj | Add-Member noteproperty -name Permission -Value $ace.FileSystemRights
            Write-Output $obj | Export-Csv -Path Z:\PowerShellTest\Permissions.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append 

    }
}
```